# Access JVM options in Spring's Application Context xml

Tags: spring, jvm, apache-camel, jvm-arguments

Is there any way to access any -D option value (JVM Option) in Spring's applicationContext.xml?

I am accessing Apache Camel Context through Spring's applicationContest.xml and separate out my routes or camelContexts based -Denv="preprod".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a property-placeholder configured you can access the system properties using `${env}`.

If you are using spring 3.0 or higher you can use the spring expression language support (Spel) - `#{systemProperties.env}`

Comment: I am using Spring 3.1. For this also do I need to configure property-placeholder?

Comment: no - you don't need property-placeholder for Spel - it will work by default.